# From two django signals works only the last one

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have made two signals for loggin, but works only the last one. And if I switch them still works the last. Is there any way to close this decorators or something like that?

```
@receiver(post_delete, sender = Student)
def add_score(instance, **kwargs):
   newChange = Changes(table_name = 'Student',type='delete')
   newChange.save()

@receiver(post_delete, sender = Group)
def add_score(instance, **kwargs):
   newChange = Changes(table_name = 'Group',type='delete')
   newChange.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change name of functions to something like `add_score_student` and `add_score_group`.